# File Structure in EE

Tags: templates, structure, file-manager

Just downloaded EE. Looking to use it for a project. I'm confused on there default file structure, I've found where my template lives... I'm just confused on all the other junk in the way.

I would like to have just an assets[image] folder etc. Below is what I have now. Is there a way I can reorganize this but still keep all the necessary EE files in place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

No, you can't totally reorganize the **system/user/templates** structure - ExpressionEngine needs the basic filesystem layout to be in place in order to work.

Yes, you can do as you please in your template directory (it looks like you are using **default_site**). You already have a **blog.group** directory, so you can make an **assets.group** directory along side of it to store your asset files. Any other template files you create would reference your asset files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{site_url}system/user/templates/default_site/assets.group/style.css" />
```

For what it is worth, I am in the habit of moving the **system** directory above the document root and creating a symbolic link from the document root to my template's asset directory, like so:

```
css -> ../system/user/templates/default_site/assets.group/css
fonts -> ../system/user/templates/default_site/assets.group/fonts
img -> ../system/user/templates/default_site/assets.group/img
js -> ../system/user/templates/default_site/assets.group/js
```

This makes the site a bit more secure and makes asset pathing cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but since it was bumped to the homepage, I'll add my 2 cents.

Your assets folder can be where ever you like. If they are public assets you can keep them organized in your web root as is common practice. They do not have to be stored in your templates folder, or within your ee system folder.

I'm not 100% what your asking when you mentioned "I'm just confused on all the other junk in the way." But if it helps, the 'default_site' folder is just that, as ExpressionEngine, via MSM can host multiple sites from one install, so there needs to be a way to identify them in the file hierarchy. You can change the name of your site in the CP from 'default_site' to what you prefer. The 'blog.group' folder indicates your template group as you see it in 'Template Manager' within the CP. It would translate to the path/url yourdomain.com/blog/index.

Answer (score 0):

On some sites I start at "default.site" directory as my root. Saves lots of clicking/expanding.